# Unity игрок при движении назад отзеркаливается выходя за коллайдер

Tags: c#, unity3d

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
[SerializeField] private float speed = 3f;
[SerializeField] private int lives = 5;
[SerializeField] private float jumpForce = 7f;
private bool isGrounded = false;

private Rigidbody2D rb;
private Animator anim;
private SpriteRenderer sprite;

private States State
{
    get { return (States)anim.GetInteger("state"); }
    set { anim.SetInteger("state", (int)value); }
}
private void Awake()
{
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
    sprite = GetComponentInChildren<SpriteRenderer>();
}
private void Run()
{
    if (isGrounded) State = States.Run;
    Vector3 dir = transform.right * Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
    transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, transform.position + dir, speed * Time.deltaTime);
    sprite.flipX = dir.x < 0.0f;
}
private void FixedUpdate()
{
    CheckGround();
}
private void Update()
{
    if (isGrounded) State = States.Idle;
    if (Input.GetButton("Horizontal"))
        Run();
    if (isGrounded && Input.GetButtonDown("Jump"))
        Jump();
}
private void Jump()
{
    rb.AddForce(transform.up * jumpForce, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
}
private void CheckGround()
{
    Collider2D[] collider = Physics2D.OverlapCircleAll(transform.position, 0.3f);
    isGrounded = collider.Length > 1;

    if (!isGrounded) State = States.Jump;
}
```

}

public enum States
{
Idle,
Run,
Jump
}

вот код при движении влево все нормально

Answer (score 0):

Установить pivot в редакторе спрайта SpriteEditor на центр персонажа. Теперь при flipX в SpriteRenderer персонаж отразится относительно этого центра.